# Removing zigzag line joining data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting using the matplotlib.pyplot plot() method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.plot(df_both_grouped['TSD_mean'], df_both_grouped['hgd_mean'], 'or', color = 'blue')
plt.errorbar(df_both_grouped['TSD_mean'], df_both_grouped['hgd_mean'], yerr = df_both_grouped['TSD_err'], xerr = df_both_grouped['home_goal_err'], color = 'blue')
```

Everything works great except I cannot seem to get rid of the annoying zigzag line that connects my points (example below).

[image]

N.B: There is an additional fitting line I wish to keep. I didn't add the code for brevity.

Is there an argument that I need to add/remove? I am sure this is a simple issue, but it is driving me insane ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the *fmt* argument of the *errorbar* method.

Simply change your code to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.plot(df_both_grouped['TSD_mean'], df_both_grouped['hgd_mean'], 'or', color = 'blue')
plt.errorbar(df_both_grouped['TSD_mean'], df_both_grouped['hgd_mean'], yerr = df_both_grouped['TSD_err'], xerr = df_both_grouped['home_goal_err'], color = 'blue', fmt='None')
```

to get rid of the connection lines as documented [here (errorbar)](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/axes_api.html?highlight=errorbar#matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar).

Actually, you can also use the *linestyle* or *ls* argument (comming from the resutling [Line2D](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) object), like with the ordinary plot command.

```
plt.errorbar(df_both_grouped['TSD_mean'], df_both_grouped['hgd_mean'], yerr = df_both_grouped['TSD_err'], xerr = df_both_grouped['home_goal_err'], color = 'blue', ls='None')
```